# AT 09 BLE module not transmitting data

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, ble

I have recently started working with the Arduino Pro Mini 5v/16Mhz and an AT 09 BLE module for an IoT project. I am controlling the BLE module using Software Serial and am leaving the hardware serial for for my laptop. I am using an app called "Serial Bluetooth Terminal" on Android to send/receive messages. The BLE module is able to receive messages and the "AT" command is also working. But when I try to get the BLE module to send a message, I get no response in the app. Any idea why this is happening and how can I resolve it?

My connections are:

> Laptop -> Arduino UNO, MB-102(USB to breadboard power adapter)
> Arduino UNO(without IC) Rx -> Pro mini Tx0
> Arduino UNO(without IC) Tx -> Pro mini Rx1
> Arduino UNO(without IC) RESET -> Pro mini Rst
> MB-102 5V -> Pro Mini Pin RAW
> MB-102 GND -> Pro Mini Pin GND
> Pro Mini Pin 2 -> AT 09 TXD
> Pro Mini Pin 3 -> AT 09 RXD
> Pro Mini Pin VCC -> AT 09 VCC
> Pro Mini Pin GND -> AT 09 GND

This is my code:

```cpp
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial ble(2, 3);

int statePin = 4;
char c;
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ble.begin(9600);
  ble.print("AT\r\n");
  delay(100);
  while(!ble.available())
    Serial.print(".");
  while(ble.available())
  {
    Serial.print(char(ble.read()));
  }
}

void loop() 
{
  while(ble.available() > 0)
  {
    c = char(ble.read());
    delay(10);
    Serial.print(c);
    ble.print(c);
  }
}
```

This is the first time I am posting here so please tell me if I missed out on any information.

Comment: You have not connected the STATE signal?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Was I supposed to? Edit: The state pin does not seem to be doing anything. It seems to be grounded irrespective of connection status. Verified with a multimeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my AT 09 module is most likely faulty. I got a new HM 10 and connected it without changing any connections or code and it worked like a charm.
I do not know the exact nature of the defect but since the chip was responding to commands, I think the PCB might have been damaged.